# Exclude questions from review that I have answered

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, vote-to-close

I was reviewing close votes yesterday, and one of the questions I was offered to review was one that I had previously written an answer for.

In hindsight, perhaps it would have been a good candidate to close, but having written an answer for it I found myself in a position where I had a conflict of interest.

I opted to 'skip' the review, but I wonder if it would be a good idea to exclude questions from being reviewed by people who have already posted an answer for it?

Anyway, just a suggestion.

Comment: Just a reminder, we may flag our own questions to be closed as dupe/off-topic/whatever... That is a massive conflict of interest though rare...

Comment: dupe-voting yourself isn't a huge conflict of interest. Of course, if you close-vote for another reason, perhaps you should delete the question instead (or not post at all)